# Database connector giving error: "Bulk mode operations require a Iterable/Iterator as payload. Got java.util.LinkedHashMap instead"

Tags: mule, datamapper

I'm using a datamapper to transform the payload to a collection prior to passing it to the database connector.  What am I missing here?

Here's the code:

```
    `<data-mapper:config name="CSV_To_Map"`  

transformationGraphPath="csv_to_map.grf" doc:name="CSV_To_Map"/>
    <batch:job name="batchcustomerimport3.6.0Batch1">
        <batch:input>
            <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\hhernandez\testworkspace411\batchcustomerimport3.6.0Collection\src\test\resources\in" moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFileName]" moveToDirectory="C:\Users\hhernandez\testworkspace411\batchcustomerimport3.6.0Collection\src\test\resources\out" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
                <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="CustomerImportTest.csv" caseSensitive="true"/>
            </file:inbound-endpoint>
            <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
            <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_Map" doc:name="CSV To Map"/>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:input>
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
                <db:update config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[UPDATE FBF05P
SET STORE#X = #[payload['STORENO']]
WHERE VIP#X = #[payload['CUSTID']]]]>
                </db:update>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
        <batch:on-complete>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </batch:on-complete>
    </batch:job>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your batch step to update records using batch commit.like

```
<batch:step name="Batch_Step">
    <batch:commit doc:name="Batch Commit" size="500">
        <db:update config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query>
                <![CDATA[
                    UPDATE FBF05P
                    SET STORE#X = #[payload['STORENO']]
                    WHERE VIP#X = #[payload['CUSTID']]
                ]]>
            </db:parameterized-query>
        </db:update>
    </batch:commit>
</batch:step>
```

As your input is list but in batch step it would be single record which is Map. So with batch commit you can send bunch of records for update.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you very much for your quick response.